# ¿Cómo realizar un unit test a la siguiente función?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jest, unittest

Tengo este código en react para una página, lo que hace es validar el `token` y mostrar una lista de productos

```
export async function getServerSideProps(
    context: GetServerSidePropsContext
): Promise<GetServerSidePropsReturn> {
    const cookies = cookie.parse(context.req.headers.cookie ?? "")
    const cookieAccessToken = cookies[COOKIE_KEY.ACCESS_TOKEN]

    if (cookieAccessToken) {
        const { data } = await getPrivateAlgoService({ accessToken: cookieAccessToken })
        return {
            props: {
                products: data ? data.results : [],
            },
        }
    }

    const { data } = await getPublicAlgoService()
    return {
        props: {
            products: data ? data.results : [],
        },
    }
}
```

Estoy intentando realizar un unit test con jest, pero no logro retornar los valores del endpoint `getPublicAlgoService`.

```
it("Should render the body with yours products list", async () => {
    const context = {
        req: {
                headers: {
                    cookie: "" 
                } 
            } 
    };
    
    const data = await getServerSideProps(context as GetServerSidePropsContext).then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
    });
})
```

Alguna idea?

Comment: Al ser un unit test se esperaría que mockearas las funciones `getPrivateAlgoService` y `getPublicAlgoService` para controlar el resultado y la ejecución de tu función para poder testear los diferentes escenarios

Comment: De hecho, tengo un mock server bajo una colección de postman que simula los endpoint. El problema que tengo radica en cómo retorno la respuesta de "getServerSideProps" que es una promesa en mi archivo test, me sale siempre <pending>